# Visual studio code: AWS CDK unit test failing - "Resolution error: ID components may not include unresolved tokens"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, tdd, aws-cdk

I have the following unit test in `test_infra_stack.py`:

```
def test_s3_bucket_block_public_access():
    """Function testing if the S3 bucket has public access"""
    app = cdk.App()
    testing_stack = InfraStack(
        app,
        construct_id="s3-stack",
        tags={"project": "infra", "environment": "dev"},
    )
    test_template = Template.from_stack(testing_stack)
    test_template.has_resource_properties(
        type="AWS::S3::Bucket",
        props={
            "PublicAccessBlockConfiguration": {
                "BlockPublicAcls": True,
                "BlockPublicPolicy": True,
                "IgnorePublicAcls": True,
                "RestrictPublicBuckets": True,
            }
        },
    )
```

When I run this test it fails with this error:

```
jsii.errors.JavaScriptError: 
  @jsii/kernel.RuntimeError: Error: Resolution error: ID components may not include unresolved tokens: infra-ingestion-snowflake-${Token[AWS.Region.8]}-${Token[AWS.AccountId.4]}-dev.
```

This happens because the testing module in Visual Studio Code is not able to use the env variables that I setup in `env` file (stored at the root folder in the project):

```
CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT=11111111111
CDK_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-central-1
```

`Settings.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/me/project/venv/bin/python3",
    "terminal.integrated.env.osx": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
    },
    "python.testing.pytestArgs": [
        "."
    ],
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
    "python.envFile":   "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
}
```

I also tried setting up the env variables directly into the `launch.json` such as:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}${env:PYTHONPATH}",
                "CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT": "11111111111",
                "CDK_DEFAULT_REGION": "eu-central-1",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run `cdk diff` in the terminal after setting up both variables there it works fine.Tehrefore, I am sure code is working, but not the test because it's not finding the variables.

Do you know the correct setup?

Answer (score 0):

According to the AWS Docs, you can simply supply an env paramete to be passed into your Stack's constructor. That way you do not have to rely on resolving environment variables at all. Since this is simply a test, there should be no problem in putting in any hardcoded value, as the purpose is to make sure the desired bucket properties are present.

Their example

```
env_EU = cdk.Environment(account="8373873873", region="eu-west-1")
env_USA = cdk.Environment(account="2383838383", region="us-west-2")

MyFirstStack(app, "first-stack-us", env=env_USA)
MyFirstStack(app, "first-stack-eu", env=env_EU)
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html

Comment: I can't harcode it because these tests are gonna be run in CI/CD Pipeline. Also I have different environments, so the account id will change when deploying to a different environment.